# "Display" checkbox to show/hide media reference field items?

Tags: 8, entities

### Background

In Drupal 7, a file field does have a "Display" checkbox per field item, to show / hide the respective file.

In a Drupal 8 migration project, we are migrating such fields as multiple-value media reference fields.

### Problem

Unfortunately, these fields don't have the "Display" checkbox. Instead, this checkbox is now on the file field in the media entity. But at least in theory, one media entity can be referenced from different nodes, and each could require a distinct setting for show / hide.

### Question

Is there any solution to add such a checkbox to a media reference field?

### Solutions considered so far

I could extend the reference field type, adding another column. Seems like a lot of effort, so I would first want to look for existing solutions.

I could also use paragraphs, where the paragraph item would have a file field and a checkbox field. However, in the edit form this would look quite cluttered compared to the nice table in D7. And it would still require custom code to control the show / hide behavior.